# Find initial value and growth in exponential growth model

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

I was given two models each with specific time($t$) and end amount($P$). $100$ after $3$ hours and $400$ after $5$ hours. Using the exponential growth model I get these $100=Pe^{3r}$ and $400=Pe^{5r}$. I heard you are suppose to divide these two so after that I got this: 4$=Pe^{5/3}$. Then I did the natural log of both and got this $r=0.831774$. After words I have to find the the end amount but I have no Initial Amount($P$). Only the rate and time. Advice?

Comment: You have rate and the amount at 3 hours.  Look at the equation you have everything except P.  Why can't you find it

Comment: If i do 100=Pe^(0.83177*3) I get 4.60517=2.495322 when I take the the natural log of both sides. The P isn't there so I can't get what P equals. That's where I'm stuck on. I don't know what I'm missing. edit: wait I see the problem now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$100=Pe^{3r} \\400=Pe^{5r} \\ \implies 4 = e^{5r-3r}=e^{2r} \\ \implies r=\ln2\approx0.693$$
Substitute $r$ in any equation to get the $P$.

Comment: You don't divide 5 and 3. Ok thanks for telling me.